# Angular multi-step form flow architecture

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I'm looking for advice on the 'Angular way' to construct a multi-step form for an SPA I am developing.

The app has three parts which I am displaying with a material design accordion:

1. Enter an ID
2. Enter generic details
3. Run a script based on a few extra input variables

I would like to implement a feature whereby, upon entering an ID and moving to step 2 of the form, a database query is run to see if 'generic details' already exist for that ID and if they do, to load them into the form fields.

I'm sure I could fudge a solution by hijacking necessary events and changing input field values manually but my experience of this approach to date is that it doesn't necessarily play well with features that Angular forms possess (e.g. validation). My question is essentially: what form(s) architecture should I use?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

P

29.3.18 Edit: I should have mentioned that submission of step 2 should send ID from 1 and generic details from 2 to a database. Submission of 3 should run a script based on extra input variables, the ID from 1 and optionally, the generic details from 2!

Comment: Take a look at https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: As Tomasz said, your best shot is the Material stepper, which is specifically designed with a wizard-like workflow in mind.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, thanks for that but my question still remains, how should the underlying form be structured? The example there suggests a separate formGroup for each step?